# How to put multiple conditions in a single if statement in R?

Tags: r

I put two conditions in a single if statement (as given in the example below), but in RStudio console after running it is giving the following message: "Error in if: missing value, but TRUE/FALSE is required".

Need someone's help to debug this script.
Thanks in advance!

```
observe({
  if (is.na(data$df$x1) && !is.na(data$df$x2)) {
    data$df$Sum <- data$df$x2 + data$df$x3
  } else if (data$df$x1 == 0) {
    data$df$Sum <- data$df$x2 + data$df$x4
  } else {
    data$df$Sum <- data$df$x2 + data$df$x1
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is total fine to as many conditions as you like in a single `if()` statement. Not sure what `observe()` is about, and it is hard to test if you don't provide a reproducible example.

The potential problems I can see here is the use of `&&`. Be aware that `&&` only compare the first element in the two columns, so do make sure that is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your `if` does not evaluate a single TRUE or FALSE value (which should be for an `if`). Use `ifelse` for vectorized operations (or you can use loop or `apply`.

```
observe({
  data$df$Sum <- ifelse(is.na(data$df$x1) & !is.na(data$df$x2), 
                        data$df$x2 + data$df$x3, 
                        ifelse(data$df$x1 == 0, 
                               data$df$x2 + data$df$x4, 
                               data$df$x2 + data$df$x1))
})
```